# iPhone Jailbreak Experts - Accessing the email storage?

Tags: iphone, email, storage

Is this possible? I have emails stored on my iPhone that are no longer accessible anywhere else, and I'd like to copy them out. I could forward them through a different account, but there are hundreds, so I'm looking for a shortcut.

I'm more than happy using the command line and playing with SQLite DBs that I know Apple use for some things on there, I just don't have much experience with the file structure on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, emails are not backed up by iTunes/iCloud, so you'll need to go deep into the filesystem (you need to be jailbroken).

Assuming you are, then these are the steps you need to follow:

1) SSH into var/root/library/Mail
2) The mail database is contained inside a file called EnvelopeData. There is no .sqlite extension, but it is an SQLite database
3) Open the SQLite database using a program like MesaSQLite
4) Extract

I haven't personally tested this, but it should work.